# GPUImage : Applying filter with brush stroke

Tags: ios, xcode, image-processing, gpuimage

Currently I am working on a photo editing *iOS* application and I am using brad's `GPUImage` framework to process images. I have applied different blend modes and it is working perfectly. But is that possible to blend an `UIImage` along with *brush strokes* ?

Whenever the user brushes over that `UIImage` the brushed part of that image should be blended with brush strokes. I am using `GLPaint` to create brush strokes.

Comment: For one, you'll need to use something other than Apple's GLPaint example. It uses OpenGL ES 1.1, and GPUImage requires a 2.0 context. You'll either need to rewrite that example or come up with your own way of making brush strokes on an OpenGL ES 2.0 canvas.

Comment: Thanks brad. I am working on OpenGL ES 2.0 to create brush strokes.